# What factors are considered when choosing a Mars lander landing site?

Tags: mars, lander

NASA seems to have a mission planned to send a 2016 lander to Mars, and they say that they are in the process of choosing landing targets. What factors are considered when selecting these sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This presentation for Mars Exploration Rover landing site selection](http://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/mer/March_2002_presentations/Adler/adler_landing3-factors.pdf) gives a good overview of the typical engineering considerations for a robotic Mars science mission landing site.  [This paper](http://www.mars.asu.edu/christensen/docs/golombek_mersites_jgr.pdf) gives more details including the science considerations.  MER is a good example for the consideration of safety, mission success, and science objectives for landing site selection.

You can find a large amount of material on the Curiosity landing site selection [here](http://marsoweb.nas.nasa.gov/landingsites/index.html).

InSight is a little different from previous landing site selections, though similar to the one for Mars Pathfinder in some ways.  For InSight, the selection has fewer factors to consider, since the science mission doesn't care very much about the characteristics of the landing site.  All they really need for the science is good contact with firm ground for the transmission of seismic signals.  The InSight landing site selection is all about landing safety and solar power for the mission.

InSight recently narrowed down to four landing sites: Elysium, Elysium, Elysium, and Elysium.  They're all in the same place since it is a uniquely large, flat, low rock abundance site, near the equator for good solar power.  [This paper](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2013/pdf/1691.pdf) provides many more details on that site selection.

Answer (score 1):

The landing site selected based on two factors

- scientific factors
- engineering factors

**Scientific Factors**:

The landing site must be selected such that it should be very close to the testing area (such as habitable zone)
where experiments are to be conducted
 It include geological , mineralogical, and 
meteorological.

**Engineering Factors**:

It is protect
the rover because of the engineering constraints. Includes  dust
factors (Mars’ ubiquitous red dust
can interfere with all sorts of
machine parts and instruments,
particularly optics which was a
problem experienced in the last rover
missions Spirit and the still working
Opportunity), atmospheric conditions
during landing, elevation of the
Martian surface, surface roughness
and inclination and finally solar
surface.

Surface roughness and inclination is a
major factor for missions especially
those that use airbags to cushion
their landings.